# How do I compare two audio signals with different sampling frequencies in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm trying to better understand upsampling and downsampling, and am using an audio signal to do so. I start with a base sampling rate of 66.15kHz, upsample by 2, run it through an LPF (sample rate of 66.15kHz, cutoff frequency of half that), then downsample by 2.

To visualize the differences between the initial and final signal, I created two spectrograms, with different sampling frequencies. There's lots of clear similarities, as well as a tighter band around the signals in the lower frequency version (as a result of the upsampling?), but I think the best thing to do is just take some sort of subtraction of the images. The problem is that the matrices are different sizes, so I can't use approaches found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443854/how-to-do-subtraction-between-2-spectrogram-and-then-draw-a-new-one-in-matlab) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298644/how-to-compare-two-audio-signals-with-matlab).

Should I just upsample both of them to be the same size? Will the differences still be there?

The spectrograms in question:

[image: Spectrograms]

Here's the code I used, some parts are commented out that may help to visualize things along the way:

```
%clc, clear all, close all;

NFFT = 1:10:4000; % used like F in the spectrogram fxn
WINDOW = 2000;
NOVERLAP = 0;

preupsample = audioread('audioclip.wav');
Fo = 66150;
orig_nyq = Fo/2;
U = 2;
D = 3;
postupsample = upsample(preupsample, U);

[preLPF, ~, W] = myfft(postupsample,U*Fo,length(postupsample));

% figure, plot(W,mag2db(abs(preLPF))), xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Magnitude Response (dB)');
% title('Magnitude Response after upsampling');

filterorder = 100;
Fpass = orig_nyq;
Fs = U*Fo;
Rpass = 0.00057565; % .1dB passband ripple
Rstop = 1e-4; % -80dB stopband attenuation
LPF = firceqrip(filterorder,Fpass/(Fs/2),[Rpass Rstop],'passedge');
% fvtool(LPF,'Fs',Fs,'Color','White');

filtered_upsample = filter(LPF,1,postupsample);
[postLPF, ~, W] = myfft(filtered_upsample,U*Fo,length(filtered_upsample));
% figure, plot(W,mag2db(abs(postLPF))), xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Magnitude Response (dB)');
% title('Magnitude Response after applying LPF');

postdownsample = downsample(filtered_upsample,D);
[postDS, w, W] = myfft(postdownsample,U*Fo/D,length(postdownsample));
% figure, plot(W,mag2db(abs(postDS))), xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'), ylabel('Magnitude Response (dB)');
% title('Magnitude Response after downsampling');

%[~,F1,T1,P1]=
figure, spectrogram(preupsample(:,1),WINDOW,NOVERLAP,NFFT,Fo,'yaxis');
%[~,F2,T2,P2]=
figure, spectrogram(postdownsample(:,1),WINDOW,NOVERLAP,NFFT,Fo*U/D,'yaxis');
% surf(T2,F2,10*(log10(abs(P2))-log10(abs(P1))),'edgecolor','none');
% view(90,-90);
% axis tight;
```

The contents of myfft.m:

```
function [X, w, W] = myfft(x, F, N)
    X = fftshift(fft(x, N));
    w = fftshift((0:N-1)/N*2*pi);
    w(1:N/2) = w(1:N/2) - 2*pi;
    W = F*w;
end
```

Comment: Can you add the two spectrograms you are talking about please? It would make the question a lot clearer and allow to check is the `fft` is correctly used

Comment: I added them to the body of the question.

Comment: What are the sizes of your matrices pre and post upsample, filtering and downsample?

Comment: Original: 675000x2, Upsampled: 1350000x2, Filtered: 1350000x2, Downsampled: 450000x2

Comment: maybe you could ask this question in [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do I just post it new or is there a crossposting feature?

Comment: You could resample the signals to a common multiple sampling frequency, but this is computationally inefficient. Another way is be to compare them over a number of samples. E.g. with a signal that has 3/2 times the sample frequency of another, you could compare the average (or whatever calculation) of three samples with the average (or whatever calculation) of two samples of the other signal. You basically do a calculation over a certain time window, which is comparable to downsampling your signals to the same lower frequency. Beware, this might induce aliasing, so LPF them first is necessary.